# Jetpack Compose Navigation: How to navigate from a root graph to a specific screen in the bottom bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-navigation

I created my navigation graphs to navigate inside my Android Application. The graphs work correctly, in fact it is possible to navigate inside my app, navigate between the bottom bar item and navigate to detail screens.

But I found that I have an error when I try to navigate from `NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.OverviewScreen.route` to `NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Profile.route` which is a specific screen of the bottom bar?

The error is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination cannot be found in the navigation graph`.

Instead, if I try to navigate from `NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.OverviewScreen.route` to `NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.route` works correctly.

**I understood that the problem lies in the fact that the bottom bar uses a different `NavHostController` but, how can I solve this problem?**

If I share my root NavHostController for the bottom bar I obtain this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModelStore should be set before setGraph call`.

---

Below the code.

The root navigation graph

```kotlin
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavigationRoute.AuthenticationGraph.route,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        authNavGraph(navController = navController)
        mainScreenGraph(navController = navController)
        detailsNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

The main screen graph

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainScreenGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {

    navigation(
        route = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.route,
        startDestination = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.MainScreen.route
    ) {
        composable(route = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.MainScreen.route) {
            HomeScreen(rootNavController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

The home screen with my bottom bar

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    rootNavController: NavHostController,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Home.route
        ) {
            homeScreen(
                navController = rootNavController,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The home screen graph with the three screen thar are in my bottom bar

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    composable(route = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Home.route) {
        ScreenContent(
            name = BottomBarScreen.Home.route,
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.route)
            }
        )
    }
    composable(route = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Profile.route) {
        ScreenContent(
            name = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Profile.route,
            onClick = { }
        )
    }
    composable(route = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Settings.route) {
        ScreenContent(
            name = NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Settings.route,
            onClick = { }
        )
    }
}
```

The details nav graph

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.detailsNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    navigation(
        route = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.route,
        startDestination = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.InfoScreen.route
    ) {
        composable(route = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.InfoScreen.route) {
            ScreenContent(name = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.InfoScreen.route) {
                navController.navigate(NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.OverviewScreen.route)
            }
        }
        composable(route = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.OverviewScreen.route) {
            ScreenContent(name = NavigationRoute.DetailsGraph.OverviewScreen.route) {
                // THIS NOT WORK
                navController.navigate(NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.Profile.route)

                // THIS WORK
                navController.navigate(NavigationRoute.MainScreenGraph.route)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and maintain two different **NavHostController** using *rememberNavController()* in each composable. In the composable that uses both, make sure to use appropriate navController to navigate.

In this case, you need to enclose the bottombar navigation in a separate NavHost and with it's own controller and make appropriate navigation calls. Hope this helps you!